# Visiting all nodes of a directed graph exactly once (not dfs)

Tags: greedy-algorithms, minimum-spanning-tree, hamiltonian-path

Consider a directed unweighted graph (in a adjacency matrix for example), how can I visit each node exactly once? By once I mean for example in a DFS traversal, a node can get finished and we should go back to it's parent node and try other paths. But what's an algorithm that doesn't get back to the parent node at all and just traverse each node once.
Consider someone who is going different places(as nodes of a graph) and can only use path given in the problem. But when he visits someplace, can't go back there no matter what.

I tried DFS on different nodes (minimum in_degree,... ) , topological sorting nodes, tried to find MST but nothing worked.
Is there any greedy way you can think about?
(considering such a way exist for this problem)

Comment: What if your digraph is a tree? Then following a path will lead to a node with no outgoing edge. How then will you proceed to the other nodes? Can you restart at some unvisited node?

Comment: no you can't. the problem states that given a set of nodes and edges, it's gauranteed such a path exists. algorithm just has to find it

Comment: "i tried ... topological sorting nodes" - is the graph a DAG? Also, please capitalize letters properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for a Hamiltonian Path (or a Hamiltonian cycle if you need to return to your original starting point).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path

It is NP-hard to determine whether a graph has such a Path. That is, there is no known polytime algorithm for it, and if you are trying to code up your own solution, you basically should perform a brute-force backtrack search through all possibilities. There will not be a greedy way to solve this with full certainty.

It is a well-studied problem and you might be able to find some implementations or libraries that have this function or approximations of it.